# how to get the parameter value using QueryString in CrystalReportViewer_init function in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, parameters, query-string, crystal-reports-viewer

I am trying to pass parameter from one page to another page. I am using `CrystalReportViewer` on the other page.

There is `CrystalReportViewer1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)` function, there I should receive the `filename` from the previous page

Here is my code

```
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument _rdStudents = new ReportDocument();

    string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReportFiles/Inventory/" + Request.QueryString[" filename "].ToString());
    //string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReportFiles/Inventory/WeightBarcorde.rpt");    This code is working
    _rdStudents.Load(reportPath);     
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = _rdStudents;
}
```

Here is my parameter **http://localhost:55047/CrytalReportTest.aspx?filename=WeightBarcorde.rpt**

```
<a target="_blank" href="CrytalReportTest.aspx?filename=WeightBarcorde.rpt">WeightBarcorde.rpt</a>
```

Can we pass parameter inside init function? or What is wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the white spaces from your query string.

Change:

`Request.QueryString[" filename "]`

to:

`Request.QueryString["filename"]`

Write to the VS output console to see if it's actually reading the parameter:

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(reportPath);`

This answer could also help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2827025/1821637